# AVAudioEngine - how to apply different bandwidth on each ear on headphones

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer, avaudioengine

I'm using `AVAudioEngine` and `AVAudioUnitEQFilterParameters` to apply some frequency and bandwidth to sound.

When I use headphones, I hear the same effect on each ear. How can I set one bandwidth value to only left ear and other to the right ear?

I'm using `Objective-C`

Answer (score 0):

Audio file must have two channels(stereo). One for left and other for right. You need to check the file type. Is it stereo type or having single channel.
If file is stereo type, then you can apply filter on left,right or both channels.

Comment: I've checked and audio file have two channels. Can you tell me more how to apply filter on left and right channel?

Comment: Freqency is attribute of audio file. You can set it using core audio.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/CoreAudioOverview/CoreAudioEssentials/CoreAudioEssentials.html

Comment: Standard frequency is 44.1 khz, you can change it using core audio.